# Graphs goes everywhere

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I've include some graph in my document but the graphs are goign everywhere, 2 pages later, or they just go at end, or they can go 2 subsection under it.

Can you help me

Here is my code:

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{Chute de la tension première expérience}
\label{fig:Chute Tension 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
no markers,
xmin=0, xmax=200,
ymin=12.3, ymax=12.7,
ylabel = $U$,
xlabel = {$Temps (secondes)$},
]
\draw[<->,thin] (axis cs:60, 12.621) -- node [right]{$\Delta U$} (axis cs:60, 12.380);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:60, 12.621) -- (axis cs:20, 12.621);
\addplot [color=blue] table [x=Temps, y=U1, col sep=comma] {test2.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Augmentation de l'intensité première expérience}
\label{fig:Augmentation Intensite 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
no markers,
xmin=0, xmax=200,
ymin=0, ymax=7,
ylabel = $I$,
xlabel = {$Temps (secondes)$},
]
\addplot [color=red] table [x=Temps, y=I1, col sep=comma] {test2.csv};
\draw[<->,thin] (axis cs:40, 1.1308) -- node [right]{$\Delta I$} (axis cs:40, 6.0160); 
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:25, 1.1308) -- (axis cs:40, 1.1308);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: float environments as `figure` is, should not be inside `\begin{cener}` ... `\end{center}`

Comment: I've just remove the `\begin{center} \end{center}`but I still got the problem.
Thank you

Comment: please provide complete small document which we can test it. btw, provided code fragment  contain tables unknown to us, so can't be compiled.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-floats.html

Comment: I've added a link for the csv file

Comment: Yeah my bad I've never seen it when i've searched answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution,
I was using the option `[h]`in my code and i needed to use `[H]` 
Now all problems are fixed.
Thank you
Jules

Comment: Hi. From your code this is not plausible: You need the package called **float** afaik in order to be able to use the option **H**.

Comment: use option `H` is not a good solution, far better is `htb`...

Comment: Objection your honor, that's heresy. :)